# How to get first value from query which returns type?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a type defined as:

```
CREATE TYPE typ_1 AS
   (result integer,
    pp1 integer,
    pp2 integer);
```

I have a function `func1` which returns `typ_1`

When I do: `select func1()` i get 3 values in one column like: `(1,2,3)` or `(1,,)`

How can I modify the query to get only the first value?
I tried `unnest` but it doesnt work with this type.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correct you use `()`

```
 SELECT (func1()).result, (func1()).pp1, (func1()).pp2
```

Yes. In my case

```
CREATE TYPE map.get_near_link AS
   (link_id integer,
    distance integer,
    sentido integer);


SELECT (map.get_near_link( x, y, azimuth)).link_id
FROM avl_db.avl_pool
LIMIT 1
```